# Changing a view from a controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, view, controller

I am new to angular and I am having trouble updating my view when a variable is changed. I am trying to update the view to show the new value of team. Here is my controller.

```
app.controller('CompetitionController', function ($scope, $log, competitionService, teamService) {

competitionService.getCompetitions().success(function (response) {
    $scope.competition = response;
}, function (reason) {
    $scope.error = reason.data;
});

$scope.team;
$scope.getTeams = function (competitionId) {
    teamService.getTeams(competitionId)
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.team = response;
            $log.info($scope.team);
        })
        .error(function (response) {
            console.log('Get Teams Error: ' + response);
        });

}

});
```

This is my view.

```
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="t in team track by $index">
                                <td>{{t}}</td>
                                <td>{{t}}</td>
                            </tr>   
                        </tbody>
```

This view is loaded up initially having no value for team, the value of team is the updated after the getTeams function is called from another view. The getTeams function is called using ng-click. Thanks!!

Edit full view

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" ng-controller="CompetitionController">
<div class="widget flat radius-bordered">
    <div class="widget-header bg-themeprimary">
        <span class="widget-caption">Flat Tabs in Widget</span>
    </div>
    <div class="widget-body">
        <div class="widget-main ">
            <tabset flat="true">
                <tab heading="Teams">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="t in team track by $index">
                                <td>{{t}}</td>
                                <td>{{t}}</td>
                            </tr>   
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </tab>
                <tab heading="Venues">
                    <p>Food truck fixie locavore, accusamus mcsweeney's marfa nulla single-origin coffee squid.</p>
                </tab>
                <tab heading="Players">
                    <p>Etsy mixtape wayfarers, ethical wes anderson tofu before they sold out mcsweeney's organic lomo retro fanny pack lo-fi farm-to-table readymade.</p>
                </tab>
            </tabset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Solution: Thanks all for the help, i figured out what the problem is. I had 2 views calling the same controller, so each view was creating a version of the controller and so the variable was not being updated between the view. I will use a factory to change the variables so each controller can have access to it.

Comment: what is the output of `$log.info`

Comment: I get an array of teams. Each team is just a string of team names

Comment: Can you show us all the html? It seems right from the code you have provided.

Comment: also share the array

Comment: the array looks like this in the console, ["AFC Bournemouth", "Arsenal FC", "Burnley FC", "Chelsea FC", "Crystal Palace FC", "Everton FC", "Hull City AFC", "Leicester City FC", "Liverpool FC", "Manchester City FC", "Manchester United FC", "Middlesbrough FC", "Southampton FC", "Stoke City FC", "Sunderland AFC", "Swansea City AFC", "Tottenham Hotspur FC", "Watford FC", "West Bromwich Albion FC", "West Ham United FC"]

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: console $scope.team, if it displays valid array.. it should work as in codepen - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/WxYkRg

Comment: $scope.team gives a valid array from inside the getTeams function but does not give a valid array from outside the getTeams function even after the function is called.  It does not seem to update the team variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors with the code: 
1) You are using success and error for the get method promise response. But then you are using a  mix of both. It should either be

`competitionService.getCompetitions()
    .success(function (response) {
        $scope.competition = response;
    })
    .error(function (reason) {
        $scope.error = reason.data;
    });` 
or it should be as

`competitionService.getCompetitions().then(function (response) {
        $scope.competition = response;
    }, function (reason) {
        $scope.error = reason.data;
    });`

Using the second method for the response is preferred as success and error is deprecated in Angularjs.

For viewing,

```
 <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="t in team">
           <td>{{ $index }}</td>
           <td>{{ t }}</td>             
       </tr>   
       </tbody>
```

This will give you a row of all the team names in the table. yo dont have to use track by $index.

Comment: Thanks! I changed my controller and view but i still have the same problem. The view still does not show the new team values

Comment: here is a working fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/nehatrajan/Lvc0u55v/8086/

Comment: Thanks! it works if i use an array instead of a function. The $scope.team variable is not updated outside of the function and remains undefined. I want to update it inside the function and the variable outside the function reflect that change. It seems i am having a scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
app.controller('CompetitionController', function ($scope, $log, competitionService, teamService) {


$scope.team=[];
competitionService.getCompetitions().then(function (data) {
$scope.competition = response.data; //Assuming response have data key
 }, function (err) {
                $scope.error = err;
            })

$scope.getTeams = function (competitionId) {
    teamService.getTeams(competitionId)
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.team = response;
        }, function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            })

}

});
```

in html this

```
<tr ng-repeat="t in team track by $index">
           <td>{{t}}</td>
 </tr>
```